# What is the difference between \unexpanded and \protected in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, expansion, e-tex, protected-macro

*EDIT: It turns out that `\unexpanded` in ConTeXt is different from `\unexpanded` in ε-TeX, so the earlier description doesn't apply. I'll update the question accordingly.*

From the ε-TeX manual:

> - Protected macros (defined with the `\protected` prefix) are not expanded when building an expanded token list (for `\edef`, `\xdef`, `\message`, `\errmessage`, `\special`, `\mark`, `\marks` or when writing the token list for `\write` to a file) or when looking ahead in an alignment for `\noalign` or `\omit`.

From [the ConTeXt Wiki](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/System_Macros/Expansion_Control):

> When expansion of a macro gives problems we can precede it by `\unexpanded`, like so:
>
> `\unexpanded\def\somecommand{... ... ...}`
>
> This will prevent the macro from being expanded in places where no typesetting occurs, like when strings are written to the tuo file.

In practice, I've seen the two used in seemingly the exact same situations, although `\unexpanded\def...` seems more common. Is there any notable difference between the two that I should be aware of?

Comment: `\unexpanded\def` is only used by ConTeXt, which has different namings.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned in the original post that I'm working with ConTeXt, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I compile with `context` the following

```
\show\unexpanded
```

I get

```
> \unexpanded=\protected

tex error       > tex error on line 1 in file /Users/enrico2013/provaccia/sep2018/tttsssttt.tex: ?

l.1 \show\unexpanded


1 >>  \show\unexpanded
2
```

In `/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/syst-aux.mkiv`, line 61 reads

```
\let\unexpanded\normalprotected
```

If I add `\show\normalprotected`, then the output is

```
> \normalprotected=\protected
```

Of course, the meaning of `\unexpanded` could be reassigned, but macros defined when `\unexpanded` has that meaning will be `\protected` (in e-TeX lingo).

Comment: I did look through `syst-aux.mkiv` and found that line, but given David Carlisle's answer and the fact that I get different errors when I use `\unexpanded` vs. `\normalprotected`, I'm no longer so sure that they're the same, or whether the ε-TeX definition is still relevant.

Answer (score 9):

**This is comparing the etex primitive `\unexpanded` not the context macro of the same name. The Question has since been clarified that the context command was what was intended.**

---

They are not really comparable:

`\protected` is a modifier of `\def` and makes the resulting token have an internal flag set so that its expansion is suppressed in certain contexts. So it is a property of the *command*.

`\unexpanded` is used to prevent the expansion of a token list so it is a property of the context not of the commands that are in it.

Of course there is some overlap, if you are writing to a file and need to prevent expansion then you could (as in classic latex) declare that fragile commands will fail and so arrange that all definitions are made with `\protect` so there are less fragile commands.  Or you could use `\unexpanded` and prevent all expansion whether or not the commands are made with `\protect`, this would also stop any user defined commands expanding to their replacements which may or may not be what you want, depending on circumstances.

Comment: @G.S. no that's a syntax error unexpanded works like `\edef\foo{zzz \unexpanded{... \scarymacrohere..} zzz}`  that is it does the same as `\the\toks@` in an `\edef` without the need for using a toks register. It is unrelated to definitions.

Comment: Oh I see from comments under the question you are comparing the etex primitive `\protected`  to the context macro `\unexpanded` rather than to the etex primitive `\unexpanded`  That might explain the question:-)

Comment: To use the `\unexpanded` primitive in ConTeXt you have to use `\normalunexpanded`.

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster Thanks, but it turns out I actually meant to ask about ConTeXt's `\unexpanded` macro (I've updated the question). Mostly I've been indecisive on whether to add `\unexpanded` or `\normalprotected` before definitions, especially since `\setuvalue` & similar commands defined in `syst-aux.mkiv` use `\normalprotected` while most other uses of `\def` I've seen in the source code use `\unexpanded`.

Comment: @G.S. You should ask these questions on the ConTeXt list because only Hans Hagen can give you an answer for this.